# How do I manage development and production settings in the same Procfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, procfile

I am using a `Procfile` for some of my dynos on Heroku, but I have different commands for both my local development and the Heroku production environment.

But given that I have one `Procfile`, how do I add a conditional to the check to see if the local rails environment is production or development?

Is that even possible?

Comment: Use the ENV vars Luke :)

Comment: How do I use ENV vars to specify things like this: `resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=7 QUEUE=\* bundle exec rake resque:work`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here.

1. Use a different `Procfile` for development. If you had say `Procfile.development` then you can specify to use it with `heroku local -f Procfile.development`.
2. Alternatively, switch to using config vars for your resque setting.

eg, with a `Procfile` as:

```
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=7 QUEUE=\* bundle exec rake resque:work
```

change it to:

```
resque: env TERM_CHILD=$TERM_CHILD RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=$TERM_TIMEOUT QUEUE=\* bundle exec rake resque:work
```

and then set `TERM_CHILD` and `TERM_TIMEOUT` config vars.

Locally you'd set them in your `.env` or on Heroku via:

```
 heroku config:set TERM_CHILD=1 TERM_TIMEOUT=7
```

Comment: I actually don't use `heroku local`. How would I specify to use `Procfile.development` if I am using just my regular `rails s` and foreman, etc.?

Comment: `heroku local` is just a wrapper onto `forego` - a Go implementation of foreman, just do `foreman start -f Procfile.development` and it will work.